# How to combine multiple device css to one class

Tags: html, css

i need to know it is possible to combine multiple device css to one class.

---

### Normally we use like this:

```
*CSS side*

@media (max-width: 991px) { .padding-991 {padding-left: 300px;} }

@media (max-width: 767px) { .padding-767 {padding-left: 100px;} }

@media (max-width: 479px) { .padding-479 {padding-left: 500px;} }

*HTML side*

<div class="padding-991 padding-767 padding-479"></div>
```

---

### Here example that i've testing but not work.

```
*CSS side*

.padding {

@media (max-width: 991px) {padding-left: 300px;}

@media (max-width: 767px) {padding-left: 100px;}

@media (max-width: 479px) {padding-left: 50px;}

}

*HTML side*

<div class="padding"></div>
```

So i need to know it is possible to combine multiple device css to one class.

Comment: The first approach is the right one, but instead of naming the classes for the breakpoints, just have .padding in each of the media queries and it will override based on the screen size. You only need the one class name.

Comment: Thanks @JHeth! Thats the actual answer that i need of the question. LOL

Answer (score 3):

You should like that.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
   .padding {
      padding-left: 300px;
   }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .padding {
      padding-left: 100px;
   }
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
   .padding {
      padding-left: 50px;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarify the example. Help a lot for newbie like me